# How do I use translated taxonomy terms in exposed views filters?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

I have a multilingual website with 5 languages.  I want to add exposed filters to the top of my views generated pages. Everthing works fine in English, my source language, but when I create a view for a foreign language and create the exposed filter for taxonomy, I can only choose the English list. I thought this would translate automatically once the page changed languages, but this is not the case.

To see what I am talking about, please click here
http://noboribetsu-spa.jp/ja/泊まる

What module do I need or what do I need to do to get these transalted terms to show up in the exposed filter select list?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this is to use the i18nviews module, which is independent of the modules included in i18n. Once the module is installed then in your view chose Filter: Has taxonomy (translated terms).  Even though the selection will be in the source language they will then translate properly on the page views.

Note: at the time of this post il8nviews is in development, has little to no documentation, and is a bit difficult to work with, but hopefully that should be cleared up soon.